# Let a, b and c be distinct nonzero real numbers. If a + 1/b = b + 1/c = c + 1/a , then show that |abc|= 1.

Tags: linear-algebra

Kindly name or state each proof that you are going to use in this statement. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you write the equation in the body of the question, it is currently unclear whether it is a + 1/b or (a+1)/b

Comment: @spyr03 i think it would be $a + \frac 1b$ since he used space between + and let the divide (/) stick between 1 and b

Answer (score 3):

$a+1/b=b+1/c \implies bc(a-b)=(b-c)$

calculate all 3 such equalities and  multiply them and cancel $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$ from both side to get $a^2b^2c^2 =1 \implies |abc|=1$.